# a simple way in the server side to get all items in the RadListBox (UI for ASP.NET AJAX) after they have been reorder by the user

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

Is there a simple way on the server-side to get all items in the RadListBox (UI for ASP.NET AJAX) after they have been reordered by the user (either by the up-down arrows or drag and drop)?

I have a save button which when the user clicks on it I need to get the items in the ListBox so I can update the indexes of the items in my model.

I'm using Telerik Rad Controls version 2019.3.1023.45 on asp.net 4.8 web forms project (Visual Studio 2019)

One of the things I was trying and did not work was to run all over my model items and find each item in the RadListBox using FindItemIndexByValue methods but it didn't work I kept getting the items in there original state/location in RadListBox even that on the UI I do see the items in the new order as I click
the up or down arrows or when i"m dragging and dropping an item.

My RadListBox has custom HeaderTemplate and custom ItemTemplate in the markup (aspx file) and I set the  AllowReorder="True" EnableDragAndDrop="True" properties and also AutoPostBackOnReorder="true".

Looking forward to some help with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the server side reordered event you should be able to grab it there in the correct order:

```
protected void RadListBox1_Reordered(object sender, RadListBoxEventArgs e)
{
    LogEvent(sender, "Reordered", e.Items);
}
```